# Dart Error - Exception has occurred. LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'results' has not been initialized.)

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

I have an error, please help Exception has occurred.
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'results' has not been initialized.)

The error, why?

[SS My Source Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbBJ4.png) And [SS My Souce Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHYJM.png)

Comment: 1. Don't post code as screenshots. 2. Your `LoginUser.fromJson` constructor doesn't initialize `results` on all code paths.

Comment: I have tried to post questions for code but the result I can not send questions, therefore I do screenshots

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I can not send questions".  Copy and paste the code you're asking about.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you you called a late variable. By saying a variable is late, you promise Dart that you will initialise this late value later in your code. See the below code for example:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late String i;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    i = 'Some String';
  }
```

When you do not initialise the variable properly, you will get a runtime error.

I have seen your code images. You are fetching data from api, so it needs time and your app views are loaded way before the data arrives. That's why you get the error. Either make your list nullable or assign a value. For example:

```
List<WelcomeModel> results = [];
```

or

```
List<WelcomeModel>? results;
```

Assigning an empty list is a safer option, as i think your list view builder will get the size of the result list and when results are loaded use setState to display updates.

Comment: Okay, I'll try.

Comment: If the answer helps you, pls select it as an Answer.

Comment: the way you love I have tried, thank you there is no error but my data does not appear, only appear NULL that's why huh? sorry my English is a hassle I need the help of google traslate for translators :D

Comment: Now when you get the value. Use setState in your stateful widget

Comment: For a moment, I tried first.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what kind of source code? I'm still learning darts.

Comment: Show me the code for your Stateful Widget where you display the results List.

Comment: Also, in your first screenshot when you do 'results.add(new Results.fromJson(V))', use a print statement to check if data is added to results list. Example: "print(results.toString())"

Comment: I've given you this command under the code you're referring to. but the result remains I/flutter (3999): null

Comment: List<Results> results = [];
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
        print(results.toString());
        // results.addAll<Results>;
      });

output in debug console = null

Comment: If after print(results.toString()) you still get NULL. Then the results.fromJson is null. Please check your API RESPONSE first

Comment: I have checked and the data I requested to the API is correct, but debug console always displays NULL results

Comment: But in your code I do not see any api call or http requests. Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: from import 'package:flutter123/auth/auth_repository.dart'; in the file auth_repository there is an API request